# Preserving CRLF characters when rendering an ERB file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, newline

I'm trying to render an ERB file through Passenger which is saved with DOS-style CRLF line breaks, but the line breaks are getting converted to just LF. Is there an option one can pass to the 'render' method that forces ERB to preserve CRLF line breaks? I'm currently using "render(:content_type => 'text/plain', :layout => false)" but that is not doing the trick.